# Populate Power Apps choice field from a button

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-form, powerapp

I've got a SharePoint list form I've customized with Power Apps.

What I want to do is to give the users buttons to click that will set the Status field to one of the choices in the options list based on the button clicked (Submitted, Approved, Rejected, Returned, etc).

I don't want the users manually changing the Status field. What's the right syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. I think you can try to use combo box, and set the Items of combo box as below:

   ```
   Choices('SP list'.ChoiceColumnName)
   ```
2. Set the following formula to `OnSelect` property of "Submit" button:

   ```
   Set(Var, LookUp(Choices('SP list'.ChoiceColumnName), Value="Submitted"))
   ```

   Similarly you can set `OnSelect` property of all other buttons.
3. Set the following formula to `DefaultSelectedItems` of combo box:

   ```
   If(IsBlank(Var), Parent.Default, Var)
   ```

**Reference**: [Change the value of a dropdown by clicking a button](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Change-the-value-of-a-dropdown-by-clicking-a-button/td-p/385822)

You can also check below link for more information:

[Update SharePoint list choice column (dropdown) with a button click](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Update-SharePoint-list-choice-column-dropdown-with-a-button/td-p/195711)

Comment: When I try to use your formula ( If(IsBlank(var), Parent.Default, var), what I get is Invalid argument type (Control). Expecting a Record value instead.